# Event handlers. (Uncaught ReferenceError: validate is not defined")

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JS and HTML and I have been practicing creating forms in HTML and using event handlers to improve interactivity but once I input data into the form, there is no output as required.The page refreshes and it doesnt show the results required as per the JS file. I have looked at the code countless times and I am simply lost.Please help.

```js
var century, year, month, day, dayValue,gender;//Get input from user
var maleNames=["Kwasi:Sunday","Kwadwo:Monday", "Kwabena:Tuesday" ,"Kwaku:Wednesday","Yaw:Thursday","Friday:Kofi","Saturday:Kwame"];
var femaleNames=["Sunday:Akosua","Monday:Adwoa:","Tuesday:Abenaa","Wednesday:Akua","Thursday:Yaa","Friday:Afua"];
var dayNames = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday","Saturday" ];
function inputFromUser() {
century= parseInt(document.getElementById("CenturyDigits").value);
year= parseInt(document.getElementById("YearDigits").value);
month= parseInt(document.getElementById("Month").value);
day = parseInt(document.getElementById("Day").value);
}
function getDayValue (){
  inputFromUser();
  d=(((century/4)-2*century-1)+((5*year/4))+((26*(month+1)/10))+day)%7;
  console.log(d);
  return (Math.floor(d));
  if (d < 0) {
      d = d * -1;
    }
    else if (d > 0) {
      return d;
    }
}
function getGender(){
  var gender = document.getElementsByName("gender");
  if(gender[0].checked == true){
    var gender = "male";}
  else (gender[1].checked == true)
    var gender = "female";
  }
  switch(gender){
    case gender="male":
      switch(dayValue){
        case(1):
        document.getElementById("Results").innerHTML="You were born on " +dayNames[0] + " and Your akan name is " +maleNames[0];
        break;
        case(2):
        document.getElementById("Results").innerHTML="You were born on "+dayNames[1] + " and Your akan name is " +maleNames[1];
        break;
        case (3):
        document.getElementById("Results").innerHTML="You were born on " +dayNames[2]+ " and Your akan name is " +maleNames[2];
        break;
        case(4):
        document.getElementById("Results").innerHTML="You were born on "+dayNames[3] +  " and Your akan name is " +maleNames[3];
        break;
        case(5):
        document.getElementById("Results").innerHTML="You were born on "+dayNames[4] +  " and Your akan name is " +maleNames[4];
        break;
        case(6):
        document.getElementById("Results").innerHTML="You were born on "+dayNames[5] +  " and Your akan name is " +maleNames[5];
        break;
        case(0):
        document.getElementById("Results").innerHTML="You were born on "+dayNames[6] + " and Your akan name is " +maleNames[6];
        break;
      }
      break;
      case gender= "female":
      switch (dayValue ){
        case(1):
        document.getElementById("Results").innerHTML="You were born on "+dayNames[0] + " and Your akan name is  " +femaleNames[0];
        break;
        case( 2):
        document.getElementById("Results").innerHTML="You were born on " +dayNames[1] + " and Your akan name is " +femaleNames[1];
        break;
        case( 3):
        document.getElementById("Results").innerHTML="You were born on " +dayNames[2] + " and Your akan name is " +femaleNames[2];
        break;
        case(4):
        document.getElementById("Results").innerHTML="You were born on " +dayNames[3] + " and Your akan name is " +femaleNames[3];
        break;
        case(5):
        document.getElementById("Results").innerHTML="You were born on " +dayNames[4] + " and Your akan name is " +femaleNames[4];
        break;
        case(6):
        document.getElementById("Results").innerHTML="You were born on " +dayNames[5] + " and Your akan name is " + femaleNames[5];
        break;
        case(-0):
        document.getElementById("Results").innerHTMl="You were born on " +dayNames[6] + " and Your akan name is " +femaleNames[6];
        break;
      }
      break
      default:
  }
function findName(){
  dayValue= getDayValue();
  getGender();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewreport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Know the day you were born and your Akan name.</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display.min.css">
    <linl href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/scripts.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid banner">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-md">
            <div class="navbar-brand">AKAN NAME GENERATOR.</div>
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2 info">
          <h1 class="text-center">ARE YOU READY?</h1>
          <p class="text-center">Do you want to know which day you were born?</p>
          <p class="text-center">Do what to find out your Akan name?
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-md text-center">GET STARTED</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid new">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-title">
              <h2>WHAT ARE AKAN NAMES?</h2>
              <div class="card-body text-center">
                <p class="intro2">Akan names are derived from Ghanian culture. Frequently in Ghana, children are given their first name as a 'day name' which corresponds to the day in the week they were born.</p>
                <p><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akan_names">Find out more about Akan names here</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <form name="AganNames" class="form" onsubmit="validate();" action="#" method="get" id="form-user">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="CenturyDigits">CenturyDigits</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="CenturyDigits" id="CenturyDigits" placeholder="eg. 19 in 1999" required
              min="0" max="20"
              >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="YearDigits">YearDigits</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="YearDigits" id="YearDigits" placeholder="eg. 99 in 1999" required min="0"
              max="99"
              >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Month">Month</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Month" id="Month" placeholder="eg. 4 for April" required min="1"
              max="12"
              >
          </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Day">Day</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Day" id="Day" placeholder="eg. 12th of April" required min="1" max="31"
              >
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="male">Male</label>
              <input  type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="gender" id="male" value="male" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="female">Female</label>
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" required>
              <br>
              <a href='#Results'>
              <button id="button-submit" type="submit" class="button button-primary mb-2" onclick="findName()">Get Akan Name</button></a>
              <button id="button-reset" type="reset" class="button button-primary mb-2" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
              <p id="Results"></p>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the function `validate` in your JS which you are calling `onsubmit` ? You do not have function like that. It will be throw `(Uncaught ReferenceError: validate is not defined")` its the does not exist and you are calling

Comment: You have `onsubmit="validate();"` which means when your form is submitted, the browser will run the code `validate()`. Your JavaScript doesn't have any `validate` function defined.

Comment: I have cleared onsubmit since I had not included the function and the error is gone.Thank you.Once I refresh the page and input data again,it refreshes and then no result is displayed.I know the form is working since the # sign in the address url bar is present.What I cant figure out is why the data I input on the form wont interact with the JS file